# Constructor of a class with an attribute that is another class object

Tags: c++, object, constructor, attributes, declaration

Constructor declaration:

```
Funcion(std::string cveFunc=" ", int numP = 0, Hora hour(0,0), int room=0);
```

Constructor:

```
Funcion::Funcion(std::string cveFunc, int numP, Hora hour(), int room) : 
    cveFuncion{cveFunc}, numPeli{numP}, hora hour = {}, sala{room}{}
```

**The problem is with the attribute hour i don't know how to declare it correctly.**

This is the class hora constructor:

inside class:

```
Hora(int hhh=0, int mmm=0);
```

outside class:

```
Hora::Hora(int hhh, int mmm) : hh{hhh}, mm{mmm} {}
```

Comment: In the declaration, `Hora hour(0, 0)` is not correct; if you want to provide a default, you need `Hora hour = Hora(0, 0)`

Comment: Prefer all-English identifiers, chances are that you'll be sharing code with others (and if it is only here on SO...) and you cannot expect everybody to understand mother tongue (or would you immediately expect `Uhrzeit` being the same as `hora`?). Admitted, in given case guessing is pretty simple, but in more complex scenarios... Additionally, I consider such wild mixture of languages unaesthetic.

Answer (score 1):

Use of

```
Funcion::Funcion(std::string cveFunc, int numP, Hora hour(), int room)
```

is wrong because in that context `hour` is declared as a function that takes no arguments and returns an `Hour`. You need to remove the `()`. Use:

```
Funcion::Funcion(std::string cveFunc, int numP, Hora hour, int room)
```

Assuming `hora` is the member variable of the class, the member initialization also needs to be updated to:

```
cveFuncion{cveFunc}, numPeli{numP}, hora {hour}, sala{room}
```

Put together, you have:

```
Funcion::Funcion(std::string cveFunc, int numP, Hora hour, int room) :
        cveFuncion{cveFunc}, numPeli{numP}, hora {hour}, sala{room}{}
```